# .htaccess redirect rewrite rule with slug and params coming from an old WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, parameters, query-string

I moved away from a WordPress site and need to clean up some page redirects. Feel like this should be easier but I'm stuck on the slug with parameters, and can't find a good example to figure it out.

I simple need to create a .htaccess 301 redirect rule from...

```
https://same-domain.com/people/?g=Joe Smith
```

to

```
https://same-domain.com/item-list?people=Joe Smith
```

with "Joe Smith" being changing value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty straight forward. You need a combination of a `RewriteCond` to capture the query string and a `RewriteRule` to perform the actual redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^g=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?people/?$ /item-list?people=%1 [R=301,L]
```

This will work in the central http server's configuration or likewise in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") in the http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

Comment: Perfect! Looks like I wasn't capturing the query correctly and thought my issue was in the `/?g=`.  Thank you for the quick help and lesson!

Comment: Answer is correct but I'll note that with the white space sometimes in the parameter, I needed to add NE to `[R=301,L,NE]`.

Comment: Well, that actually depends on your processing logic, not really the rewriting rule. Great that you solved your task, though!